# What are the settings for interactive video on FLASH?

Tags: flash, video, settings, interactive

what is the best option for a web site like this

http://www.luchtmachtbase-x.nl/main.php#app=2f14&e9ba-location=

I want my website has the same functional. Thankss!!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple flash website But the animations are another thing..
Your settings would really be standard.
its seems to me that website usses a lot of hd streaming with alph channel overlaying other elements, could be preloaded but the site seems slow.

The functionality is standard doesnt really seem to be much interaction as there animated clips playing at certain events.

If you are really good at animation show some samples i would like to see some, i could help you put together a website for fun